# Column flow from one page to another?

Tags: two-column, cv, text, layout

I'm working on a project that has several columns,

I'd like to have the text from the columns flow from one page to the next, you know, Word-style.

Is this possible? I'd love to be able to do it without having to change the text manually from one page to the other.

For reference, I'm working off the forty seconds cv class.

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/forty-seconds-cv/pztcktmyngsk

Answer (score 2):

Class `forty-secons-cv` is designed for one page: you have to define the content for the first page  and for an second page if needed separatly ...

So, no, it is not possible with that cv template ...